# Outputting the batch script console output to a log file?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I'm having trouble doing this properly. After searching old posts, the below batch command should work, but my newly created text file is resulting in an empty text file. So whatever is outputted to the console doesn't seem to be outputted to my text file.

```
> test.txt (
instagram-scraper atlanticbonito --tag -d="C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Daily Instagram Scraper Database\Atlantic_bonito" --latest -t image -m 10
echo testing
)
```

The command is `instagram-scraper atlanticbonito --tag -d="C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Daily Instagram Scraper Database\Atlantic_bonito" --latest -t image -m 10`

which outputs a string "Starting scraping" followed by an update of how many images were found etc. All of this info/text is being outputed to the console, but I can't seem to direct it the `test.txt` file.

From what I understand there seems to be 3 different type of outputs to the console, so maybe I'm not directing the correct output?

Thank you.

Comment: `>>test.txt 2>&1 (` should _append_ all _standard_ and _error_ streams into `test.txt` file.

Comment: using `(whatever)>> text.txt` is easier and clearer looking and easy to remember

Comment: @SlickNutz   Thank you for this tip -- def. looks cleaner.

Comment: @JosefZ  Thank you. it seems to be working now. Only problem, is the entire output (many lines) are being outputted as a single line - Is there an fix for this?